# How can I fix my site for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design

Here is an [about me page](http://the4dpatrick.github.io/aboutmatthew) and here is the [GitHub](https://github.com/the4dpatrick/aboutmatthew)

I've been making the website responsive and even tools like protoFluid to view it as if it was on an iPhone. However, I used my iPhone and there are numerous problems. The buttons does not seem to want to change their widths even though they are based on percentages. They are overflowing to the right and leaving a black space to the right.

```
.container .name .social div{
        width:  80px;
        display: inline-block;
}
.container .name .social img{
        width: 100px;
}

.social {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline;
        width: 425px;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .social {
        padding: 0;
            width: 424px;
        position: relative;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto
    }
    .name .social div {
            width: 16.6666667%;
    }
    .social img {
            width: 125%;
            /*width: 100px*/
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
        .container .name .social div {
                width: 13.6667%;
        }
        .container .name .social img {
                width: 125%;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to solve it, include using bootstrap framework... I always use a "resize window" chrome plugin(found in appstore [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh)) , and the error is showed. And you can work it in your dev enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons stay the same because the percentage width is decided on the size of parent controller. On line 271 of stylesheet.css `.social` class has width 425px (the same width it has on each screen size) so the buttons stay the same. Try changing width of .social class  or simply use pixels for button dimensions for that media-query - `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)`

Comment: I added margin: 0 auto to the class in @600px, and it seems to work. There is a margin to the right however.

Comment: That is not margin, .social div is centered but the divs inside are not, they're simply aligned to the left. Since your divs inside .social parent div are inline-block elements the easiest solution is to simply add text-align:center; on .social div